# ¿Como cambiar varios valores iguales en 1 ArrayList y poder hacer una suma?

Tags: java, arraylist

Crea un `ArrayList` de nº enteros y muestra su contenido por pantalla. Permite que el usuario introduzca un número y si se encuentra en la lista, si dicho nº es mayor o igual que 5 restále 2, y si es menor, súmale 1, y si no está en la lista, añádelo a la misma.
El problema lo tengo al querer hacer operaciones

```
public class Uso_Iterator {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Integer valor=0;
        int numIntro;
        Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);

        ArrayList<Integer> numeros=new ArrayList<>();

        numeros.add(10);
        numeros.add(20);
        numeros.add(3);
        numeros.add(4); 
        numeros.add(7);
        numeros.add(3);
        numeros.add(7);

        Iterator it=numeros.iterator();

        System.out.print("Lista inicial: ");
        while(it.hasNext()){
            System.out.print(" " + it.next() + " "); //recorremos el ArrayList 
        }

        System.out.println("\nIndique que nº quiere modificar de la lista ");
        numIntro=sc.nextInt();
        sc.nextLine();//liberamos buffer

        if(!numeros.contains(numIntro)){
            numeros.add(numIntro);
            System.out.println("Añadiendo nuevo valor a la lista ...." + "\nLista final " + numeros);
        }
```

**Aquí es donde debería de cambiar algo o crearme una variable + pero no se como hacerlo**

```
        else{
            it=numeros.iterator();//que empiece de nuevo 
            while(it.hasNext()){
               //System.out.print(" " + it.next() + " "); //recorremos el ArrayList 
                it.next();
                if(numIntro>=5 ){ //si es mayor o igual que 5 restale 2 sino sumale 1 
                    numeros.equals(numIntro);
                 // numeros.set();
                    valor-=2;
                 // numeros.set(1, numIntro+valor);
                    System.out.println("Aqui estoy restando 2 " + numeros);
                 // numeros.set(numIntro, numIntro);
                 }
                 else{
                    valor+=1;
                    System.out.println("Aqui sumando 1 ");}
                 }
             }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Voy a probar a hacerlo, pero cambiando un par de cosas. No tiene porque ser exactamente con esos objetos no ?(Iterator y eso..)

Comment: Si tendria que ser con iterator para jugar con los metodos pero bueno, con un for o for each me hago una idea, muchas gracias

Comment: Ya lo tengo, pero una duda, cuando haces los calculos de si es menor que cinco y eso guardas el numero modificado en el array o simplemente haces los calculos y ya esta ?

Comment: Verás Bea deberías evitar hacer preguntas confusas o poco detalladas te sugiero que le des un vistazo a como comentar. Para concluir, coge mi código, añade un bucle y ve añadiendo a la lista, no te lo voy a escribir yo porque ni siquiera se si quieres que después compare de nuevo todos los términos y los incluya o no.

Answer (score 0):

Bueno aqui tienes el codigo, si todo lo he entendido es el siguiente :

Como puedes apreciar he cambiado tu `Scanner` por `BufferedReader` es mas potente y aconsejable.Lo he hecho lo mas **didacticamente** posible, por su puesto se puede hacer en menos lineas. Pero asi lo entenderas mejor.

Tambien he cambiado el `Iterator` por los `for` eso ya lo adaptas como creas conveniente.

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.ArrayList;

/**
 *
 * @author Jose
 */
public class Stack_pregunta {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        ArrayList<Integer> numeros = new ArrayList<>();
        int numeroBuscar = 0;
        numeros.add(10);
        numeros.add(20);
        numeros.add(3);
        numeros.add(4);
        numeros.add(7);
        numeros.add(3);
        numeros.add(7);

        //muestro los numeros
        System.out.println("Numeros en la lista =>");
        for (int i = 0; i < numeros.size(); i++) {

            if (i == numeros.size() - 1) {
                System.out.println(numeros.get(i));
            } else {
                System.out.print(numeros.get(i) + "-");
            }

        }
        System.out.println("-------------------------");

        //Pido el numero al usuario y lo guardo
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        System.out.println("Porfavor, introduzca el numero que desea buscar");
        System.out.print("-> ");
        try {
            //Me obliga a meterlo en un try-catch porque arroja excepciones
            //Si te fijas le estoy haciendo un casting al valor 
            //que guardo desde 'br.readLine()' porque siempre es un objeto de tipo
            //'String' por tanto para almacenarlo en un entero lo tengo que parsear
            numeroBuscar = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Error al pedir el numero al usuario = " + e);
        }
        System.out.println("has introducido el numero " + numeroBuscar);

        System.out.println("-------------------------");

        //Primero compruebo si esta o no en la lista
        boolean existe = numeros.contains(numeroBuscar);

        //existe => pues vamos a hacer las operaciones
        if (existe) {
            System.out.println("El numero " + numeroBuscar + " SI esta en la lista");
            //compruebo si es mayor que 5
            if (numeroBuscar >= 5) {
                numeroBuscar = numeroBuscar - 2;
            }

            if (numeroBuscar < 5) {

                numeroBuscar = numeroBuscar + 1;

            }

            System.out.println("Finalmente el numero que has introducido tiene el valor = " + numeroBuscar);

            //no existe => pues lo añado
        } else {

            System.out.println("El numero " + numeroBuscar + " NO esta en la lista. Voy a añadirlo");
            numeros.add(numeroBuscar);

        }

        //Vuelvo a mostrar los datos
        System.out.println("-------------------------");
        System.out.println("Lista antes de acabar el programa:");
        for (int i = 0; i < numeros.size(); i++) {

            if (i == numeros.size() - 1) {
                System.out.println(numeros.get(i));
            } else {
                System.out.print(numeros.get(i) + "-");
            }

        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Que quieres que se reste 2 a todos los numeros del array o al numero que ha introducido, tengo preparada una respuesta editada en la que edita todos los numeros de la lista, dime si quieres esa opcion para cambiarlo

Comment: si quiero que al final cuando vuelva a editar la lista le reste 2 a los numeros mayores o igual a 5 de la lista y los muestre y los que son menores se queden como estan y si el numero introducido es menor que 5 que a esos numeros menores de 5 de la lista le sume 1 y los otros los deje como esta siempre mostrando de nuevo la lista modificada